# Data Source from Tomcat to JBoss 6.1

Tags: tomcat7, datasource, jboss6.x

Below is the data source configuration in my Tomcat 7.

Need to convert this into JBoss 6.1, specifically the **Eviction & removeAbandoned** settings in the `standalone.xml` file.

Can anyone tell me where I can configure these settings in JBoss?

```
<Resource connectionCacheName="XXX" 
    connectionCachingEnabled="true" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory" 
    initialSize="10" logAbandoned="true" maxActive="100" maxWait="10000" minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="60000" 
    minIdle="10" removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="60" testOnBorrow="true" 
    testOnReturn="false" testWhileIdle="true" timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000" 
    type="javax.sql.DataSource" name="XXXX" url="jdbc:mysql://XXXX" 
    username="XX" password="XXXX" validationInterval="30000" validationQuery="SELECT 
    1"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this Tomcat to JBoss migration guide](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-web/jbosswebserver/tomcat-to-jboss-migration) it should be:

4.x - 5.x - 6.x ->  datasource-ds.xml file into JBOSS_HOME/server/[server-name]/deploy

7.x             ->  datasource-ds.xml file into JBOSS_HOME/standalone/deployments or as a module into JBOSS_HOME/modules